# No stories are shown when using Angular 7

Tags: angular, storybook

I'm using Storybook Version: `4.1.12` and Angular `7.2.4`.
Storybook is loaded successfully (I'm using Angular 7) but in dashboard this message is displayed:
"Sorry, but you either have no stories or none are selected somehow.".
I DO have stories under `src\stories`.
When typing garbage in `index.stories.ts` I DO get an error in dashboard (that means the file is compiled and read by storybook lib).
I've also tried to uninstall & reinstall `@angular\storybook`. Still nothing.

**To Reproduce**

Configure storybook almost exactly step by step (use angular 7):
https://storybook.js.org/basics/guide-angular/

I also needed to change `\node_modules\@storybook\angular\src\client\preview\index.d.ts`
return values of `IAPI` and `IStoribookSection` to any.

**.storybook/config.js**

```js
import { configure } from '@storybook/angular';

// automatically import all files ending in *.stories.ts
const req = require.context('../src/stories', true, /.stories.ts$/);
function loadStories() {
    req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

**.storybook/tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": [
    "../src/test.ts",
    "../src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "../projects/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "../src/**/*",
    "../projects/**/*"
  ]
}
```

**src/stories/index.stories.ts**

```js
import {AppComponent} from '../app/app.component';
import {storiesOf} from '@storybook/angular/src/client/preview';
import {moduleMetadata} from '@storybook/angular';
import {ApiServiceMock} from './api.service.mock';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

storiesOf('My Component', module)
    .addDecorator(
        moduleMetadata({
            imports: [FormsModule],
            providers: [ApiServiceMock]
        })
    )
    .add('hello world', () => ({
        component: AppComponent
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

One visible difference between the snippets above and my config is that you seem to be missing one 'require' in your '.storybook/config.js' inside the 'loadStories' function:

```js
import { configure } from '@storybook/angular';

const req = require.context('../src', true, /.stories.ts$/);

function loadStories() {
 require('../src/stories');
 req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

Using:

- Storybook core 5.0.6
- Angular 7.2.0

BTW: 
This may be unasked advice but i found it hugely beneficial to put one 'XXXXXXX.stories.ts' file for each individual component into the same place as the Presentational Components html, css and ts files